# Differentiating between password and other kind of keyboard inputs in a keylogger

Tags: c++, winapi, keylogger

I am writing a keylogger for windows. I am planning to get the pressed key with [GetAsyncKeyState(KEY)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) and a hidden console. After a key press has been identified I will get the current focused windows with [GetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505.aspx) and indentify which program was on top when the key was pressed. I also want to be able to Differentiate between key presses for passwords and other kind of inputs. Is there a way to do it? How?

I am not writing a malicious software. This is for an assignment in Advanced Programming course.

Comment: Display a window witch a check box. The user the has to check when he inputs a password.

Comment: I am writing a keylogger so the user will not even know his keyboard input has been logged

Comment: @AmirQasemi manni66's comment was clearly intended to be a joke.

Comment: You know it's a password because the focus is on a password input control. How you determine that is up to you, but judging by how often password managers get it wrong I'd say it's not easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the foreground app is using standard Win32 UI controls, then try this:

- use `GetForegroundWindow()` to get the `HWND` of the foreground window.
- then use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` and `GetGUIThreadInfo()` to get the foreground window's currently focused child control.
- then use `GetClassName()` to check if it is a standard `EDIT` control (this check might fail in some UI frameworks! You might have to use the [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) API to detect the control type)
- then use `GetWindowLong/Ptr()` to check if it has the `ES_PASSWORD` style applied.

However, if the foreground app is not using standard Win32 UI controls, and/or is custom-drawing them, or the like, then all bets are off.